# How can I embed an Instagram Video or Picture using SSL?

Tags: facebook, iframe, https, embed, instagram

I need to embed Instagram Video or Photo using the SSL protocol, so I can show it in a facebook app.

If I insert an iframe with the following URL https://instagram.com/p/hvisAyBQZ0/embed/ it will load all resources in http, but not https.

```
UPDATE:
This is the HTTPS Response, it's a 302 response.

Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 154
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Tue, 10 Dec 2013 15:58:20 GMT
Location: http://instagram.com/p/hvisAyBQZ0/embed/
Server: nginx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this old Google Groups post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/instagram-api-developers/fB4mwYXZF1c) by Mike Krieger, you can get the URL via the API, then substitute the beginning of the url with `distillery.s3.amazonaws.com`.

For example: `http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_539562_75sq_1386973442.jpg` can become `//distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_539562_75sq_1386973442.jpg` which works fine on https.

It appears Instagram now uses various CDNs, so you have to be a little smarter with the rewrite rules. Here's my code

```
def sslify_instagram_cdn_url(url):
    """Intercept IG CDN urls and serve using a SSL-friendly CDN instead"""
    replace_prefixes = (
        ('^http://images.ak.instagram.com(.*)$', '//distillery.s3.amazonaws.com%s'),
        ('^http://distilleryimage([0-9]*).ak.instagram.com(.*)$', '//distilleryimage%s.s3.amazonaws.com%s'),
        ('^http://origincache-([a-z]*).fbcdn.net(.*)$', '//origincache-%s.fbcdn.net%s'),
        ('^http://distilleryimage([0-9]*).s3.amazonaws.com(.*)$', '//distilleryimage%s.s3.amazonaws.com%s'),
        ('^http://scontent-([a-z]).cdninstagram.com(.*)$', '//scontent-%s.cdninstagram.com%s'),
        ('^http://photos-[a-z].ak.instagram.com/hphotos-ak-[0-9a-z]{3,4}/(.*)$', '//origincache-frc.fbcdn.net/%s'),
    )
    for prefix, replacement in replace_prefixes:
        results = re.findall(prefix, url)
        if not results:
            continue
        return replacement % results[0]
    return url
```

Be warned, this may break when/if Instagram changes their CDN setup. But it's a workable hack for now.

Comment: From my testing, it looks like to me that Instagram is increasingly using the Facebook CDN (fbcdn.net URLs), which is good news since those can be simply rewritten by replacing the `http://` with `//`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Instagram does not support HTTPS for traditional `<iframe>` embedding. All they do is respond with a redirect to http as you found out yourself.

Alternatively you could embed the picture itself with an `<img>` tag. The pictures can be served via HTTPS with a valid SSL certificate.

Examples:

```
<img src="//instagram.com/p/hvisAyBQZ0/media/?size=t" alt="Thumbnail (150x150)">
<img src="//instagram.com/p/hvisAyBQZ0/media/?size=m" alt="Medium (305x306)">
<img src="//instagram.com/p/hvisAyBQZ0/media/?size=l" alt="Large (640x640)">
```

All these URLs are actually redirects, but the target URL seems to support HTTPS although it's not mentioned in the [official documentation](http://instagram.com/developer/embedding/).

This is of course not a satisfying substitute for a regular embed, because Instagram videos cannot be served like this (only the preview images). But maybe it's better than nothing for some.

Comment: I cannot believe Instagram does not support SSL, what planet are they on?  Come on Instagram, please give us SSL support.

Comment: Sadly this is not a complete solution since Instagram has been supporting videos.

Answer (score 0):

For this, you'll need to implement Instagram's [Developer API](http://instagram.com/developer/).

You will notice that all of their endpoints are available over `https`, in particular...

[`https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/3?access_token=[redacted]`](https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/3?access_token=%5bredacted%5d)

...which will retrieve a particular photo or video.

Comment: But I need the native embed frame. 
However, when I retrieve a particular photo or video it's available only in http. Changing in https I have a certificate validation error.

Comment: Right - the native embed frame is only available over HTTP. If you want HTTPS, the only option is to use the developer API.

Comment: Not true, If I use API I have HTTP URL for the single image. Changing it to HTTPS, I have SSL Errors.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying. There's no way to actually load the *image itself* over SSL - they don't server them over SSL. The body of the entity would be though, ensuring all but the actual binary data is encrypted. THAT SAID: all of this is in the public domain anyway, is https really that big of a deal in the first place?

Comment: it is if you want to embed instagram pictures in facebook app. And because instagram is Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

The EFF has a great resource with Instagram cdn rewrite rules in their HTTPS Everywhere Atlas: https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere/atlas/domains/instagram.com.html

Using these you could make a somewhat more robust system for generating instagram https image links.