# Instagram Embed iframe doesn't render on secure page

Tags: ssl, iframe, https, instagram

Instagram Embed iframe doesn't render on secure page. 
iframe by itself loading via https, but it content has some insecure sources which prevents loading whole iframe.

Is there any work around?

Comment: Also answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20498347/how-can-i-embed-an-instagram-video-or-picture-using-ssl